# How to keep state across different components using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have three components and navigating between them I am using react routes.

```
import React from "react";
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/main/main.component';
import SecondView from './components/secondview/secondview.component';
import ThirdView from './components/thirdview/thirdview.component';
import Traineeship from './components/traineeship/traineeships.component';
import InformationFilter from "./components/information/information-filter.component";
import InformationJob from "./components/information/information-job.component";

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/information-filter' component={InformationFilter}/>
            <Route path='/information-job' component={InformationJob}/>
            <Route path='/traineeships' component={Traineeship}/>
        </Switch>
    </HashRouter>

);

export default AppRoutes;
```

In InformationFilter Component I use Link to navigate to the other component liek this:

```
<Link to={{
       pathname: '/information-job',
       state: {industry: this.state.selectedIndustry, job: this.state.selectedJob}
}}>
```

I can see the parameters available into InformationJob and from Information Job I pass sameway using Link into Traineeship but the problem is when I go back from Traineeship this part within InformationJob:

```
componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.location.state);
    }
```

is empty, what is the best way so that I can pass parameters from component A to B then to C so I dont have any problem when clicking back button.

Any idea about this?

Comment: It seems like the right time to use a redux based reducer.

Comment: I already achieved a solution without redux , all I did was add a root component and store the values on the root state now I have the states available acrros child components using props :)